# One to many relationship in ER diagram, MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-relationship, mysql-workbench

Hi I'm drawing an ER Diagram using MySQL Workbench for my final year project. It's about a shipping company, where buyer & shipping agent are involved in a shipping process with my client.

So far the buyer and agent have same attributes. So I decided to keep both of their data in a table and differentiate them using an attribute (*type* in my case).

[image]

As you see in my picture I couldn't able to make a N:M relationship between *shipping* table and *external* table. It always give me 1:M relationship. When I try to do the relationships manually it creates a another relational table and make a 1:M relation with it.

[image]

Can anyone assist me with my problem? Further how efficient to have a relational table in my case.

Comment: what is the problem? the correct way to make a M-to-N relationship between two tables is to create an auxiliary table and split the M-to-N in two 1-to-N relationships, just the way you did